# Items not aligning through the use of & in the aligned enviroment

Tags: alignment

Why is the code below not aligning itself in the equals sign?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{aligned}
        g'_{00} &= g_{00}, && g'_{11} &= g_{11}, && g'_{01} &= g_{01}, \\
        g'_{0i} &= R g_{0k}, && g'_{1i} &= R g_{1k}, && g'_{ij} &= R R g_{kl}
    \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are misaligned because your columns are out of sync. Change each `&&` to just `&` and it will be proper:

```
<right-aligned> & <left-aligned> & <space> <right-aligned> & <left-aligned> ...
```

For a specific instance, the first paired `&&` leaves an empty `<right-aligned>` column, and has the ensuing `g'_{11}` entry in a `<left-aligned>` column, and the `= g_{11}` entry in a `<right-aligned>` column.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. Could you explain why the use of && was wrong, please? I always used to use it like that.

Comment: For the "explain", I added a bit to the answer. As to what you have previously used, I can only guess. Maybe you are remembering a different environment. Or maybe you had equations that needed to be left aligned, rather than being aligned on an equals sign, or maybe you had a column of (left aligned) textual notations.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you switch from an `aligned` to an `alignedat` environment, for finer control of the horizontal spacing between the columns. In the example below, the horizontal space is set to `\qquad`; obviously, you're free to choose other lengths.

Whether you use `aligned` or `alignedat`, do replace the instances of `&&` with `&`.

[image]

```
With \texttt{alignedat}:
\[
\begin{alignedat}{3} % # of instances of '&' in a row: 5. (5+1)/2=3= 2nd arg of alignedat
g'_{00} &= g_{00}, & g'_{11} &= g_{11}, & g'_{01} &= g_{01}, \\
g'_{0i} &= R g_{0k}, &\qquad g'_{1i} &= R g_{1k}, &\qquad g'_{ij} &= R R g_{kl}
\end{alignedat}
\]

With \texttt{aligned}:
\[
\begin{aligned}
g'_{00} &= g_{00}, & g'_{11} &= g_{11}, & g'_{01} &= g_{01}, \\
g'_{0i} &= R g_{0k}, & g'_{1i} &= R g_{1k}, & g'_{ij} &= R R g_{kl}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```